# Unity Container passing runtime constructor parameters

Tags: unity-container

I have two constructors, the first works fine as follows:

```
    public ESite(Func<IOrg> unityOrgFactory)
    {
        this.OrFactory = unityOrgFactory; 
        this.Kid = Guid.Empty;
    }
_IoC.RegisterType<IESite, ESite>(); 
IESite eSite = boClass.IoC.Resolve<IESite>();
```

Now, I need to pass in a key at runtime so I add a constructor as usual:

```
    public ESite(Func<IOrg> unityOrgFactory, Guid kid)
    {
        this.OrFactory = unityOrgFactory;
        this.Kid = kid;
    }
```

Syntax for this registration and resolve usage? I've tried several InjectionConstructor variants but can't get it right...I'm missing something. After several search-and-try rounds, time to ask! I have read several posts on related topics...

Thanks for tips!
GG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable workaround (not necessarily the best answer) is to disencumber the constructor by moving the injected parameters to an InjectionMethod

Register:

```
// Use InjectionMethod Initializer to free up constructors. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953186(v=pandp.50).aspx   new InjectionMethod("Initialize", typeof(Database), "CustomerServices")
        _IoC.RegisterType<IESite, ESite>(
            new InjectionMethod("Initialize", typeof(Func<IOrg>)) 
            );
```

Use:

```
        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953186(v=pandp.50).aspx
    [InjectionMethod]
    public void Initialize(Func<IOrg> unityOrgFactory)
```